# What is the order of returned Types by Assembly.GetTypes()?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, .net-assembly

If I get the list of types in my AppDomain, is there an inherent ordering to these types?

```
List<Type> myTypes = new List<Type>();
foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    myTypes.AddRange(a.GetTypes());
```

This seems to produce a list that's **grouped** by types in a namespace, but I can't see a pattern to the namespace groups themselves (or the types within each namespace group).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even if you can discern an order, there's nothing in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to guarantee it - so you *absolutely* should not rely on it.

If you want a particular ordering, you should ensure it yourself.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, even though the advice is sound.

Comment: @julealgon: Well the questioner seemed to be satisfied... I guess I could explicitly say "It is implementation specific"...