# Is order of reflection deterministic?

Tags: c#, reflection

When i look i.e: for all types in an assembly implementing some interface using reflection, will the order of returned types always be the same or they can be returned in any order during different runs?

Comment: i don't think you should rely on their order as is - but you can just use LINQs `OrderBy()` to solve that. I'm curious as to why you'd need them ordered, though?

Comment: first type that is found determines which items are shown later on to the user. The order suddenly changed yesterday, just to return back to previous state today.

Comment: At a few reflection related places in the msdn are remarks like this `The GetMembers method does not return members in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which members are returned, because that order varies.`

Comment: Since meta-data upon loading type should appears in memory similarly, I'd say you can rely on the order as long as **nothing** is changed. In other words if you get results in the certain order from a certain dll, then you should always get them in this order, unless someone will change dll or a .net framework implementation (unlikely). I had issue with enum where several constants have same values and the order of their retrieval [was deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35600294/1997232) and stay so for years.

Comment: "The order suddenly changed yesterday" - so despite having evidence that the ordering is inconsistent, you asked this question? I'm confused.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the order of items was preserved for at least one year(the time i'm working on that project).  So if this order was completly non deterministic it would rather result in many more such situations. I think the answer is in Sinatr comment, and this sudden change was caused because someone added or modified something in the module that was in the same shape since its creation.

Comment: You're mistaking non-determinism and randomness.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000711/what-is-the-order-of-returned-types-by-assembly-gettypes

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation of Assembly.GetTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netcore-3.1).

> Returns
>
> Type[]
>
> An array that contains all the types that are defined in this
>   assembly.

There is no mentioning of any order. Therefore you should not rely on it. Event if ordering is consistent now, it might change in some future version.

If you want the result to be ordered, use [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1), [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1), or some of the other sorting alternatives.